# Capitalization of each sentence in a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, capitalize

This should be easy but somehow I'm not quite getting it.

My assignment is:

> Write a function sentenceCapitalizer that has one parameter of type string. The function returns a 
>   copy of the string with the first character of each sentence capitalized. The function should return 
>   “Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?” if the argument to the function is “hello. my name is 
>   Joe. what is your name?” Assume a sentence is separated by a period followed by a space."

What I have so far is:

```
def sentenceCapitalizer (string1: str):
    words = string1.split(". ")
    words2=words.capitalize()
    string2=words2.join()
    return (string2)

print (sentenceCapitalizer("hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?"))
```

Upon execution I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab3.py", line 83, in <module>
    print (sentenceCapitalizer("hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?"))
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\lab3.py", line 79, in sentenceCapitalizer
    words2=words.capitalize()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'"
```

What is that telling me and how do I fix this? I tried following instructions found on a page listed as the python software foundation so I thought I'd have this.

Comment: Note: Python 3.5 has not yet been released (it is still being developed), so your claim to be using 3.5.5 is.. surprising; you probably have a *different* version of Python, rather than having used a time machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use a string method on the wrong object; `words` is list object *containing* strings. Use the method on each individual element instead:

```
words2 = [word.capitalize() for word in words]
```

But this would be applying the *wrong* transformation; you don't want to capitalise the whole sentence, but *just* the first letter. `str.capitalize()` would lowercase *everything else*, including the `J` in `Joe`:

```
>>> 'my name is Joe'.capitalize()
'My name is joe'
```

Limit yourself to the *first letter only*, and then add back the rest of the string unchanged:

```
words2 = [word[0].capitalize() + word[1:] for word in words]
```

Next, a list object has no `.join()` method either; that too is a string method:

```
string2 = '. '.join(words2)
```

This'll join the strings in `words2` with the `'. '` (full stop and space) joiner.

You'll probably want to use better variable names here; your strings are sentences, not words, so your code could do better reflecting that.

Together that makes your function:

```
def sentenceCapitalizer (string1: str):
    sentences = string1.split(". ")
    sentences2 = [sentence[0].capitalize() + sentence[1:] for sentence in sentences]
    string2 = '. '.join(sentences2)
    return string2
```

Demo:

```
>>> def sentenceCapitalizer (string1: str):
...     sentences = string1.split(". ")
...     sentences2 = [sentence[0].capitalize() + sentence[1:] for sentence in sentences]
...     string2 = '. '.join(sentences2)
...     return string2
... 
>>> print (sentenceCapitalizer("hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?"))
Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?
```

Comment: He's asking about capitalizing the first character of each sentence, not each word. Edit: Great, you updated that to the question.

Comment: @danijar: Don't be confused by the variable names, the split is on `'. '`.

Comment: But `.capitalize()` will blow away word capitalizations, so `Joe` will become `joe`, and `' '.join` will destroy the original periods.

Comment: @DSM: I was trying to address the initial problem *first*; the solving of the whole homework problem is a little further out, don't you think? :-)

Comment: I certainly can't throw stones, given that I usually just say "you might also want to check X" at the end, but then I'm profoundly lazy..

Comment: It does the job, but I'd suggest some improvements. It doesn't work with exclamation marks, questions marks, tabs and line breaks.

Comment: @danijar: I don't think the task set by the professor requires going into that much detail about edge cases. Parsing natural language into sentences is never this simple, sure.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job. Since it extracts all sentences including their trailing whitespace, this also works if you have multiple paragraphs, where there are line breaks between sentences.

```
import re

def sentence_case(text):
    # Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
    # with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
    sentences = re.findall('[^.!?]+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)

    # Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
    sentences = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentences]

    # Combine sentences
    return ''.join(sentences)
```

Here is a [working example](http://ideone.com/fvTezY).

Answer (score 0):

To allow arbitrary whitespace after the dot. Or to capitalize the full words (It might make the difference for a Unicode text), you could [use regular expressions -- `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

def sentenceCapitalizer(text):
    return re.sub(r"(\.\s+|^)(\w+)",
                  lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).capitalize(),
                  text)

s = "hEllo. my name is Joe. what is your name?"
print(sentenceCapitalizer(s))
# -> 'Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?'
```

Note: pep8 recommends lowercase names for functions e.g., `capitalize_sentence()` instead of `sentenceCapitalizer()`.

To accept  a larger variaty of texts, you could [use `nltk` package](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch00.html):

```
# $ pip install nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 

def sent_capitalize(sentence):
    """Capitalize the first word in the *sentence*."""
    words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    if words:
       words[0] = words[0].capitalize()
    return " ".join(words[:-1]) + "".join(words[-1:]) # dot

text = "hEllo. my name is Joe. what is your name?"
# split the text into a list of sentences
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
print(" ".join(map(sent_capitalize, sentences)))
# -> Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I couldn't find this solution here.

You can use 'sent_tokenize' method from nltk.

```
import nltk
string = "hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?"
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(string)
print (' '.join([s.replace(s[0],s[0].capitalize(),1) for s in sentences]) )
```

And the output

```
Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    import textwrap
except ImportError:
    print("textwrap library module error")
try:
    import re
except ImportError:
    print("re library module errror")

txt = "what ever you want. this will format it nicely. it makes me happy"

txt = '.'.join(map(lambda s: s.strip().capitalize(), txt.split('. ')))

user = "Joe"
prefix = user + ":\t"
preferredWidth = 79

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent=prefix, 
width=preferredWidth, subsequent_indent=' ' * len(prefix) + " ")

print(wrapper.fill(txt))
```

I try to use as little amount of internet dependent functions as possible. I found this works for me, hope this is of some use to someone

Answer (score -1):

I did not use 'split' but just while loop instead. Here is my code.

```
my_string = input('Enter a string: ')
new_string = ''
new_string += my_string[0].upper()
i = 1

while i < len(my_string)-2:
    new_string += my_string[i]
    if my_string[i] == '.' or my_string[i] == '?' or my_string[i] == '!':
        new_string += ' '
        new_string += my_string[i+2].upper()
        i = i+3
    else:
        if i == len(my_string)-3:
            new_string += my_string[len(my_string)-2:len(my_string)]
        i = i+1

print(new_string)
```

Here is how it works:

```
Enter a string: hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?
Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name
```