# Capitalizing the first letter of each sentence while keeping all whitespace

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    newString = ''
    wordList = []
    numLetters = 0
    for s in usrStr.split('. '):
        if s[0].isupper():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(s)
        if s.islower():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(s)
            numLetters += 1
            
        if s[0].islower():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(s)
            numLetters += 1 
            
    newString = '. '.join(wordList)
    return newString, numLetters
```

The string being passed in is:

`i want some water. he has some.    maybe he can give me some. i think I will ask.`

Note that there are 4 spaces before `maybe`. The result that I want is:

`I want some water. He has some.    Maybe he can give me some. I think I will ask.`

but I get:

`I want some water. He has some.    maybe he can give me some. I think I will ask.`

I know that `maybe` isn't being capitalized because I split on `.` and that sentence has more than one space after the period. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320697/capitalization-of-each-sentence-in-a-string-in-python-3

Comment: Strip on ".".  Then take last letter in the words, and change to upper case.  Then join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop: 
First find the index of non-space character.
Then replace s[0] with s[index].

Comment: I attempted to do this but wasn't able to get it to work. Could you explain how I would do that, if you don't mind?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378962/returning-the-lowest-index-for-the-first-non-whitespace-character-in-a-string-in

Comment: that helped me find the index, but the part I can't figure out is how to replace the index with a capital version.

Comment: I think this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858065/python-how-to-capitalize-nth-letter-of-a-string

Comment: Is it always 4 spaces before `maybe`? if yes, then when you split them into lists, just index it as `string[4]` which would give you the word `maybe`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using regex sub method

```
def fix_capitalization(mystr):
    numLettets = 0
    newstr = []
    for s in mystr.split('. '):
        tmp = re.sub('^(\s*\w+)', lambda x:x.group(1).title(), s)
        newstr.append(tmp)
        # num of letters
        if s.lstrip()[0] != tmp.lstrip()[0]:
            numLetters += 1          
    return '. '.join(newstr).replace(' i ', ' I '), numLetters

fix_capitalization( 'i want some water. he has some.    maybe he can give me some. i think I will ask.')
# return ('I want some water. He has some.    Maybe he can give me some. I think I will ask.', 4)
```

Simple fix to original code as below

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    newString = ''
    wordList = []
    numLetters = 0
    for s in usrStr.split('. '):
        # check for leading space
        lspace = len(s) - len(s.lstrip())
        s = s.lstrip()

        if s[0].isupper():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(' '*lspace + s)
        if s.islower():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(' '*lspace + s)
            numLetters += 1
        if s[0].islower():
            s = s.capitalize()
            s = s.replace(' i ', " I ") 
            wordList.append(' '*lspace + s)
            numLetters += 1 

    newString = '. '.join(wordList)
    return newString, numLetters
```

Comment: You want to explain the line `tmp = re.sub('^(\s*\w+)', lambda x:x.group(1).title(), s)` a bit if you want this to be an instructive answer rather than just an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution uppercasing each letter after a period, ignoring intervening space.

```
def fix_capitalization(astring):
    newchars = []
    # Treat first char as if follows a "."
    prevnonspacechar = "."
    for char in astring:
        newchar = char
        if prevnonspacechar == ".":
            newchar = char.upper()
        newchars.append(newchar)
        if not char.isspace():
            prevnonspacechar = char
    newstring = "".join(newchars)
    return newstring

astring = """i want some water. he has some.    maybe he can give me some. i think I will ask."""

print(fix_capitalization(astring))
```

Output:

```
I want some water. He has some.    Maybe he can give me some. I think I will ask.
```